# Python Dataframe conditionally drop_duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to drop duplicated rows for a dataframe, based on the type of values of a column. For example, my dataframe is:

```
A    B
3    4
3    4
3    5
yes  8
no   8
yes  8
```

If `df['A']` is a number, I want to `drop_duplicates()`.

If `df['A']` is a string, I want to keep the duplicates.

So the desired result would be:

```
A    B
3    4
3    5
yes  8
no   8
yes  8
```

Besides using `for` loops, is there a Pythonic way to do that? thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new column `C`: if `A` columns is numeric, assign a common value in `C`, otherwise assign a unique value in `C`.

After that, just `drop_duplicates` as normal.

*Note*: there is a nice `isnumeric()` method for testing if a cell is number-like.

```
In [47]:

df['C'] = np.where(df.A.str.isnumeric(), 1, df.index)
print df
     A  B  C
0    3  4  1
1    3  4  1
2    3  5  1
3  yes  8  3
4   no  8  4
5  yes  8  5
In [48]:

print df.drop_duplicates()[['A', 'B']] #reset index if needed
     A  B
0    3  4
2    3  5
3  yes  8
4   no  8
5  yes  8
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution is more verbose, but might be more flexible for more involved tests:

```
def true_if_number(x):
    try:
        int(x)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

rows_numeric = df['A'].apply(true_if_number)

df['A'][rows_numeric].drop_duplicates().append(df['A'][~rows_numeric])
```